# redirect to mobile site, but show original site if user choose to see

Tags: c#, mobile

I have the requirement to redirect to mobile site when the user views our site from a mobile. 
I am ok with this, just check the device and redirect. (using HTTP_USER_AGENT) and then

```
requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("http://mobile.example.com");
```

But then on the mobile site,  if they choose to view the full site, it should allow them to do so.

There is a link in the mobile site to view the full site.

I am confused because if user clicks the link to view the full site it would again redirect them to the mobile site.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: MMmmm. I like cookies.

Comment: we do not have access to the mobile site..

Comment: I would call the main site with a querystring parameter, for instance ?shownormal=1 and then if that parameter is set, set a cookie.

Comment: Thanks Dan, that sounds reasonable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812852/full-site-link-from-a-mobile-website?rq=1

Comment: If you dont have access to the mobile site, can't you then check the refererer to see if the request comes from the mobile site, and then set the cookie?